# Prevent duplicate sum in linq group and join

Tags: c#, linq

i have two tables with linq join query :

ex:

```
MandaysReal
date       | mandays
----------------------
2015/10/15 | 5
2015/10/15 | 7

EstateAttendance
date       | mandays
----------------------
2015/10/15 | 2
```

then i join with this query and group by date:

```
var data = from m in db.ManDaysReals

       join a in db.EstateAttendances on m.Date equals a.Date
       group new { M = m, A = a } by m.Date into g
       where g.FirstOrDefault().A.Date >= startDate && g.FirstOrDefault().A.Date <= endDate
       && g.FirstOrDefault().A.Block.Section.Id == SectionId

       select new CompareMandaysViewModel
       {
          Date = g.FirstOrDefault().A.Date,
          HKMandays = g.Sum(x => x.M.Mandays),
          HKAttendance = g.Sum(x => (decimal)x.A.mandays),
       };
```

the results is showing like this:

```
CompareMandaysViewModel
date       | HKMandays | HKAttendance
2015/10/15 |    12     |      4 <-- why the result is 4 ?
```

the value of HKAttendance is duplicated, anyone can help me?

thank you

Comment: What should be the correct value for `HKAttendance` instead of 4 ? (is it 2? what is the logic for this calculation)

Comment: the value should be 2 because there is just one data in EstateAttendance

Comment: You have cartesian product when you use "join" keyword in LINQ. that means the join gives you 2 records with Mandays=2 resulting to SUm as 4.

Comment: I agree with @TechieBee. If you have any problems with long LINQ request, you can split it to several requests and check intermediate results

Comment: so what should i do?, is there any filter to check if it has more than 1 record?

Comment: In essence you need to either split the whole thing up into two different queries or you need to make it way more complicated for it to work as one single query. The question is though which variant you prefer. The later one essentially being summing up of mandaysREals and THEN only joining the second table to it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
 1. Group records separately in each table into list
 2. Join them later
See below example

```
        var xp = (from p in db.ManDaysReals
                  group p by p.Date into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Date = g.Key,
                      ManDays = g.Sum(p => p.ManDays)
                  }).ToList();

        var xa = (from p in db.EstateAttendances
                  group p by p.Date into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Date = g.Key,
                      ManDays = g.Sum(p => p.ManDays)
                  }).ToList();

        var xt =  from p in xp
                  join a in xa on p.Date equals a.Date
                  select new CompareMandaysViewModel
                  {
                      Date = p.Date,
                      HKMandays = p.ManDays,
                      HKAttendance = a.ManDays
                  };
```